# Can “ça fait” become “ça faisait”?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, temps-grammatical

If I were referring to a enclosed moment in the past, can I use the latter construction? For example if I wanted to say:
“It had only been three days since I started taking orders”, would I say:
“Ça ne faisait que trois jours que j'avais commencé à prendre les commandes”?

I have never attempted the *ça fait* construction this way, so it's likely this is completely off base so please let me know of other options.

Answer (score 3):

Your sentence is correct outside *prendre les commandes* which more often means "taking control" in French.

What you want to say can be written unambiguously:

> *Ça ne faisait que trois jours que j'avais commencé à prendre/accepter des commandes.*

*Ça fait* becomes, with changing the tense, *ça faisait*, *ça fera*, *ça ferait*, *ça aurait fait*...

Comment: It depends on the context really. "Prendre les commandes" can really be understood as "Prendre les commandes (des clients)"

Comment: @LaurentS. Correct, *prendre les commandes* is ambiguous, the reason why I replaced it by a non ambiguous phrase.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing wrong with your translation is the rendering of "taking orders"; it's "recevoir des ordres". However, that's not the only possibility; in particular you can keep the word "since".

- Trois jours seulement avaient passé depuis que j'avais commencé à recevoir des ordres.

CORRECTION

There has been an oversight from my part; it has been caught by mcadorel (see the comments); the OP's translation is also a possibility.

Comment: It looks like 'taking orders' could mean both (1/ prendre des commandes and 2/ recevoir des ordres), or even 'prendre les ordres' (en religion). OP's translation sounds legit to me!

Comment: @mcadorel It's true for "1/" and "2/" and also for "3/" except that in French you do not say "prendre" but "entrer dans" (entrer dans les ordres). The problem is just a little word, "les"; if he would have had "des" instead, it would have been unmistakably the case that "taking orders"  meant "accepting verbal or written demands for goods or services etc."; there would have been a rightful correspondence but it happens he used "les" and in French that makes for a meaningful phrase, but with a quite different meaning: "to get possession of the means of control"; how do you say that in English?

Comment: @mcadorel Note that two cases are included in my translation, "execute orders" and "accept demands for goods", that because I chose the word "order", which means "injunction to do something"  as well as "a demand for goods or a service" (a somewhat quaint coincidence). With "commande" this is not possible, only the option "a demand for goods or a service" is possible.

Comment: Oh, right, prendre les commandes ≠ prendre des commandes. You nailed it!

Comment: @mcadorel I think there is been an oversight from my part, which makes you also altogether right! It 's a matter of interpretation apparently, which the context, when stated, makes clear: orders as meaning "some orders" (des ordres (tels que d'un supérieur hiérachique)) versus "orders" (zero article) (les commandes, les ordres (demandes de marchandise, etc.)); I'm sorry for overlooking this possibility.

Comment: @mcadorel  It remains true nevertheless that, as you said, "prendre les commandes ≠ prendre des commandes". I'll let you consider the different possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "*ça fait*" can become "*ça faisait*" if you want to speak about the past.

The part "*que j'avais commencé à prendre les commandes*” sounds a little bit weird. 
Maybe use "*ça ne faisait que trois jours que j'avais pris les commandes*" because in french we understand that you started 3 days ago.

I just want to add one thing : "*ça fait*" and family ("*ça fera*", "*ça faisait*"..) are speaking language. Do not write it down. Instead you should use the 'full' word for "*ça*" wich is "*cela*".
Like this sentence : "*ça fait trois jours que je marche*" becomes "*cela fait trois jours que je marche*".
However it doesn't work everytime if you want to use "*cela*" instead of "*ça*". For instance, "*ça va*?" (How are you?) can't be "*cela va?*" because if you uppgrade the "*ça*" to "*cela*" you also have to upgrade the "*va*" to "*va-t-il*" and add a "*Comment*". So "*ça va*?" becomes "*Comment cela va-t-il?*"

Comment: "derivate" is not  a proper term; that is because there is no reason to choose the present form as a root, it is merely a radical associated to a tense as any other of the three forms, and in fact those forms coexist; you might say, a bit jocularly though, "and family" or more seriously "and associated forms", which is not the technical term as I don't know that term, but which describes the principle correctly enough for a start.

Comment: I don't get you statement about *ça fait* and *ça va*. When you write down speaking language, there is no requirement to rephrase the sentence and thus misrepresent its formality level. You'll definitely find some *ça fait* and *ça va* in prominent French authors books.

Comment: "ça fait" and "ça va" can be used but are unformal. You can write them down, of course but it's unpleasant to read in an email. In a book you can read it because it's spoken language who is writen. eg : << pierre a dit "ça fait rien" >>, what is written is meant to be spoken. But it's very unlikely to read it in a prominent French authors book elsewhere than in a sentence.